# Android layout margin doesn't apply

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I've came over a simple registration activity, I am testing my application on sony xperia neo (480x854 3.7" ~265 ppi running 4.0 ics) and on samsung gio (320x480 3.2" ~180 ppi running 2.3.6 ginger )
it works very well on xperia but it's not on samsung (the layout margin doesnt apply i guess)
any idea about what's happening?

[image]
[image]

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_img_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/reg_spinner_country"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/reg_spinner_operator"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:prompt="@string/operator_prompt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/reg_layout_bg"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_text_operator_key"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="+96279"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_text_mobile_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:ems="7"
                android:inputType="phone" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reg_but_submit"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_register"
            android:text="@string/submit_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can i use form Relative Layout and Linear Layout or Frame Layout is to be used?

Comment: I've tried it, by with RelativeLayout and it was fine in preview.

Comment: most likely framelayout but I'll try a relative one

Comment: perfect! post it in an answer so i can reward you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This , I have tried this with Relative Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_img_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/reg_spinner_country"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/reg_spinner_operator"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
            android:prompt="@string/operator_prompt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/reg_layout_bg"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/reg_text_operator_key"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="+96279"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_text_mobile_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:ems="7"
                android:inputType="phone" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reg_but_submit"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_register"
            android:text="@string/submit_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```